# Google play books reader inbuilt dictionary does not work for pdf ebooks

Tags: pdf, google-play-books

I like the [Google play books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play_Books) reader app. I generally have ebooks in PDF format. I frequently use the dictionary feature but this feature does not work for PDF ebooks. So I need to convert them in EPUB format which spoils ebook layout and format.

Just because of the missing dictionary feature for PDF ebooks I don't want to switch to another random application.

So is there any way to enable the dictionary feature for PDF ebooks in Google play books app?

Comment: Is it **all** PDF's, or just those files without text, i.e., made of *images* of the pages? For a PDF made only of images, optical character recognition (OCR) is needed to abstract text to look up.